# How to set column width

Tags: textbox, set, kendo-grid, column-width

I want to have a text box in my context menu which by default will give me my current column width(for the particular column) and then I can set new column width in px. Is this possible?

Comment: Code snippet would help here

Comment: I dont have any code for this. I only have code for my contextmenu. I am trying to find out how can i do this. I want to have a text box in the column header (right click) contextmenu where i can set column width depending of on which column it was clicked.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more as why through the column menu and not by inbuilt resizing feature provided by kendo

Comment: That is my client requirements, i know it is stupid but what can i do :) .